# Function that return unique values in a given column on dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I am trying to create a function that return unique values for a given column in a dataframe using R but I don't understand why I am getting NULL each time I try it. Here is my code :

```
Val_Uniques <- function(column_name, df){
  # we first get the dataframe columns names
  column_names = colnames(df)
  if(column_name %in% column_names){
    result = unique(df$column_name)
    return(result)
  }else{
    print("Could not find this column ! ")
  }
}
```

Comment: change unique(df$column_name) to unique(df[,column_name] and also run the function with quotation mark around column_name, something like Val_Uniques("a",df)

Comment: Oooh that was a quick fix !! Thank you very much @ShirinYavari you saved my day.